# Installing packages on windows minion with salt state files

Tags: windows, yaml, salt-stack

Im trying to install the java jdk package on a windows salt-minion through a salt state file.
On linux servers ive got it working fine with

```
packages_to_install:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - java-11-openjdk.x86_64
```

For the windows servers however this config doesnt work. Trying to search the web for what else is needed has proved fruitless so far but im guessing i need to tell the state file where to download the java package from however i cant find what the setting should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows installation you have two main options:

1. Configure and use [winrepo](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html). Note that the default JDK installer is Oracle's, which you may not be licensed to use. Create your own software definition file to override.

```yaml
Install JDK:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: jdk11
```

2. Download and run an installer.

```yaml
Download JDK installer:
  file.managed:
    - name: C:\Installers\java-11-openjdk.msi
    - source: https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.17%2B8/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.17_8.msi
    - source_hash: 9b74536f2475b67e53c83ecf41f80ac9f1ba29cef91c6e261e10d1223da42d69
    - makedirs: true
    - prereq:
      - Install JDK

Install JDK:
  cmd.run:
    - name: msiexec /a C:\Installers\java-11-openjdk.msi
    - unless: java -version | findstr 11.0.17
```

Comment: Thanks method 2 worked with a little tweaking of paths.

Comment: @jabra method 1 is recommended if you're doing a lot of Windows installers

Comment: I did try winrepo first but i dont think im configuring it properly. I am only trying to install jdk for windows so hopefully the download is ok? i am finding the command to install the msi file isnt working and when i run it locally it only works if i start the cmd line session as administrator

Comment: Oh, salt isn't running as SYSTEM? For a user install use `/i` instead of `/a`.

Comment: The example at the top of the documentation should work out of the box.

Comment: the salt minion is running as local System. i dont get an error on the master when i run the state, java is being downloaded just not installing. The winrepo link has a couple steps, the last being try a install of firefox but i just unable to locate package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251047/discussion-between-jabra-and-orangedog).